# how to code for floating touch in android app

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am developing an app that has to use a floating touch button that performs some action on click. It always remains on top in every app and other apps on screen are still accessible. This is somewhat similar to assistive touch feature in iPhone. Please can anybody help me with how to code for this feature in my android app?

Comment: See this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top

Comment: I think you should not put [ios] in the tags of this question